# Give an example of a field where -1=1

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

The question is to find a counterexample to the following:

*In every field the element $-1$ is not equal to $1$.*

My intuition leads me to integers modulo $1$.

Is this correct, are the integers modulo $1$ a field?

Comment: No, because the integers set isn't a field

Comment: "Integers modulo 1" is the trivial ring, hence not a field. Better choose "Integers modulo 2".

Comment: If $1=-1$ then $2=0$ hence...

Comment: Integers modulo $1$ are not a field. This is because one of the "axioms" for field says that the additive identity and multiplicative identity are different. Another version of the axioms asks that there be at least two elements.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ and every field of characteristic 2.